# Why onclick doesn't work on the second page request with turbolinks in Rails4 and coffeescript?

Tags: onclick, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-4

Why I have to reload the page to get an on click callback working?

Using Rails 4.0.0.rc2 I want to click on a table-row/table-td instead of a standard link.
The table-row has a css-class and a coffee-script should load the proper url when the row is clicked.

The code shown below works fine the first time and redirects to the right target.
When I then click the menu (handeled with turbolink)to show up the original table the clicks on any of the table-rows doesn't work unless I reload the table.

My haml-template looks like this

```
....
%tr{class: 'clickable-row', id: 'row-id-1'}
  %td Some text
  %td more text
%tr{class: 'clickable-row', id: 'row-id-2'}
  %td ...
  %td ...
```

The coffeescript:

```
jQuery ->
  $('.clickable-row td').click ->
    target_id = $(this).parent().attr('id').replace /row-id-/,''
    document.location = "/controller_xy/#{target_id}/edit"
```

Comment: Yvette, thank you for your hint. I'm new here (as a poster) and changed the title.

Comment: Are more `.clickable-row td` elements being added after the jQuery is run?

Comment: no, the link goes just back to the page with the table. There are also no other javascipts involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though, this is not the answer to the question 'why' but at least a workaround.

The working coffeescript looks like this:

```
jQuery ->

  $(document).on( 'click', '.clickable-row td', ->
    target_id = $(this).parent().attr('id').replace /row-id-/, ''
    document.location = "/controller_xy/#{target_id)}/edit"
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

There's another, more **simple** solution here.

When you use turbolinks, which is default since Rails 4, also include [jquery.turbolinks gem](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks).

The instructions are quite easy.

1. In your Gemfile add: **gem 'jquery-turbolinks'**
2. In your JavaScript manifest (default: app/assets/javascripts/application.js.coffee):

   Require **jquery.turbolinks** immediately **after jquery**.

   Require **turbolinks after** your **scripts**.

Example:

```
#= require jquery
#= require jquery.turbolinks
#= require jquery_ujs

# ... your other scripts here ...

#= require turbolinks
```

Comment: This is now deprecated in Rails 5